# What's wrong with this Fluent NHibernate Configuration?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

What's wrong with the following setup?  The Where filter on the AutoPersistanceModel does not appear to be working and the table name convention does not appear to be working either. The error I'm evenually getting is "The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'property' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'meta, jcs-cache, cache, id, composite-id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'."  Here's my code:

```
    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                OracleConfiguration.Oracle9.ConnectionString(
                c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")))
            .Mappings(m =>
                          {
                              m.AutoMappings.Add(GetAutoPersistanceModel);
                              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                          })
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public AutoPersistenceModel GetAutoPersistanceModel()
    {
        return AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<User>()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && type.Namespace == "Some.Namespace")
            .ConventionDiscovery.Add<IConvention>(
                Table.Is(x => "tbl" + x.EntityType.Name.Pluralize())
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James is leading you correctly but his snippet is wrong.

```
.WithSetup(s=> s.FindIdentity = p => p.Name == "ID"));
```

Is what you're after! Replace "ID" with what ever your actual property is.

Answer (score 6):

The exception is saying NHibernate has encountered a `<property />` element first, which is invalid. The first element in an NHibernate hbm file should (nearly) always be an Id, so it seems the `AutoPersistenceModel` isn't finding your identifiers.

How are your Ids named in your entities? The `AutoPersistenceModel` expects them to be literally called **Id**, if they're anything different then it won't find them.

You can use the `FindIdentity` configuration option to override how the `AutoPersistenceModel` finds Ids, which can be useful if you're unable to modify your entities.

```
// if your Id is EntityId
.WithSetup(s =>
  s.FindIdentity = property => property.DeclaredType.Name + "Id"
)
```